# Paging by item Flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll, pagination, flutter-layout, scroll-paging

i would like to achieve pagination with flutter like this: every swipe gesture there i only one page swipped, and it is being centered in the screen. on the edges of the screen you can see parts of the next and previous items i.e the item is NOT THE SIZE OF THE SCREEN. this requirement is important. i can't set the item to be the size of the screen, also it should have padding between the items. for a better understanding i have a gif attached.
Thank you.

https://gfycat.com/soreheartfeltguernseycow

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the goal easily using [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) widget.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the PageView class works properly only if the item is the width of the screen (scrolling horizontally), if you have a code that shows how to make what is suggested in the gif it would be great, thanks!

Comment: Actualliy, this is possible. You can use `PageController` for that. It has constructor parameter `viewportFraction`.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found a class carousel_slider which is easily making that functionallity under the hood using PageView as suggested above.
For anyone who will need such behaviour as in the gif, see https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider